# Android override ondraw int EditText

Tags: android

I am trying to override ondraw in EditText,use canvas to write words on EditText.
But when I setInputType in EditText,it can't display any words.
I don't know how it works.

```
    public class Input extends EditText{

        private static int paddingHintText = 30;
        private static int paddingInput = 200;
        private static int hintTextSize = 40;
        private String textString = "test";

        Paint paint;
        public Input(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.editseletor);
            setPadding(paddingInput, 0, 0, 0);
            setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
//if I use it,it can't display any words
        //setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            paint = new Paint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(50, 50, 50));
            paint.setTextSize(hintTextSize);
            canvas.drawText(textString, paddingHintText, this.getHeight()/2+hintTextSize/2-5, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(0, 50, 200, 50, paint);


            super.onDraw(canvas);

        }

        public void setLeftText(String textString){
            this.textString = textString;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to show a hint? If you are, then there's already a way to do that: `android:hint="@string/whatever"`

Comment: remove `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);` and try again

Comment: Thanks,it works.But I don't know why it is.